# Subquery optimization

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, query-optimization, notin

I was reading through this article - [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL at EXPLAIN EXTENDED](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/); I am working with an existing design.

What I want is to be able to select all id's from `table a`, which are not in `table b`.

I am using this query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM `orders` a LEFT JOIN `orders_corrected` b ON 
a.`order_id`=b.`order_id` WHERE b.`order_id` IS NULL;
```

`Table a` contains over 900K records, and `Table b` contains over 200K and growing.

The above query takes about 7-8 minutes.

I also tried using `NOT IN`, which is slow as well.

`order_id` column is NOT NULL and UNIQUE indexed.

Output of `explain`:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: a
type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 595783
Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: b
type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,order_id_UNIQUE,ix_order_id
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 152
ref: func
rows: 1
Extra: Using where; Not exists; Using index
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Since you're selecting pretty much everything (no filters) there's not that much you can do. One way of speeding it up is to keep a count column in the orders table to see how many corrected orders there are, that could give you a simple filter instead.

Comment: @Wolph That's my last resort. To add a column to the table `a`. I am doing `a.*` because all the data is required. I tried doing a `LIMIT 5` as well. Doesn't help much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to be able to select all id's from table a, which are not in table b

Use a correlated subquery in a WHERE clause involving an indexed column. For example:

```
SELECT U.Id
FROM Users U
WHERE (SELECT Count(Ph.UserId) FROM PostHistory Ph WHERE Ph.UserId = U.Id) = 0
```

**References**

- [Users with no Posts - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/692174/users-with-no-posts?opt.withExecutionPlan=true)
- [MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 13.2.10.7 Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html)
- [MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 13.2.10.10 Optimizing Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-subqueries.html)